# JPA2/EclipseLink OneToMany cascade persist issue "Referential integrity constraint violation"

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have two entities A and B:

A.java:

```
...
public class A implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "IDA", nullable = false)
private Integer ida;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String name;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
private List<B> bList=new ArrayList();

public void addB(B bp){
bp.setA(this);
bList.add(bp);
}
...
```

B.java:

```
...
public class B implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected BPK bPK;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String name;
@JoinColumn(name = "A_IDA", referencedColumnName = "IDA", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private A a;
...
```

the `bPK` field is a Composite Primary Key:

```
@Embeddable
public class BPK implements Serializable {
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "IDB", nullable = false, length = 20)
private String idb;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "A_IDA", nullable = false)
private int aIda;

public BPK() {
}

public BPK(String idb, int aIda) {
    this.idb = idb;
    this.aIda = aIda;
}
...
```

SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
idA INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idA)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
idB VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
A_idA INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idB, A_idA),
FOREIGN KEY(A_idA)
REFERENCES A(idA)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

the main code:

```
   A a=new A(null,"A1");
   BPK bpk=new BPK();
   bpk.setIdb("b1");
   a.addB(new B(bpk,"B1"));

   EntityManager em=getEntityManager();
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   em.persist(a);
   em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I get this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception  [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504):    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
 [EL Warning]: 2012-03-26 01:29:16.724--UnitOfWork(1902320872)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504):  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
 Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint  violation: "CONSTRAINT_42_1: PUBLIC.B FOREIGN KEY(A_IDA) REFERENCES PUBLIC.A(IDA)"; SQL  statement:
 Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint   violation: "CONSTRAINT_42_1: PUBLIC.B FOREIGN KEY(A_IDA) REFERENCES PUBLIC.A(IDA)";...
```

the error indicates a violation of integrity constrains, but why?
a single possibility whether the insertion of the entity B is made before A...
Any help please?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:
solved just replace this :

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "A_IDA", referencedColumnName = "IDA", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

by this one:

```
 @MapsId("aIda")
```

finally B.java:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "B.findByName", query = "SELECT b FROM B b WHERE b.name = :name")})
 public class B implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @EmbeddedId
 protected BPK bPK;
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 30)
 private String name;
 @MapsId("aIda")
 @ManyToOne(optional = false)
 private A a;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the A_AID field controlled by the  aIda attribute in the Embeddable - that means this attribute must be set with the value from A before you can persist B.

If you are using using JPA 2.0, you can mark the @ManyToOne with the @MapsId("aIda") which will allow you to remove the @JoinColumn for it.  This will make the JPA provider set the value in b.bPK.aIda with the value from A on persist.

If you are not using JPA 2,0, you can either set it yourself by first persisting A and then changing your addB method to also set B's bPK.aIda, or you can change the fields so that the JoinColumn is writable and make the bPK.aIda insertable=false, updatable=false.

Comment: Thanks Chris your answer helped me, just a small precision: netbeans generated these entities it's not me who created, I only create SQL tables....;  Is-that we must be familiar with annotations or just use an IDE that generates all that? have you  a suggestion for me?

Comment: We definitely must be familiar with the annotations. The automatic generation works well in most cases, but it might get something wrong or there are multiple options the auto annotation does not get. Therefore it is best to use the auto annotation to reverse engineer things first and then look at the annotations and fix of cull things you do not need.